# Fluent NHibernate column name conventions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to create a convention for column names using Fluent NHibernate auto mapping. There is a blog entry that states that property conventions can be set like this:

```
ConventionBuilder.Property.When(
  x => x.Property.PropertyType == typeof(int),
  x => x.ColumnName(x.Property.Name + "Num")
)
```

But the problem is, that `x` only has a `ColumnNames` *property* and has no `ColumnName` *method*. How can I change the property mapping conventions using the new style configuration?

(P.S: I'm using the latest binary avaialable on the site as of today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... it seems they changed from the ColumnName property to a ColumnNames list. You have to add your columnname to this list like this:

```
ConventionBuilder.Property.Always(s => s.ColumnNames.Add(s.Property.Name + "Num"))
```